# How to set height of parent div dynamically according to the content?

Tags: css, sass

I have a parent grey colored div container inside of which I have created a text input box which is expandable, as shown below:

I want to set the height of parent div(the grey colored one) dynamically if the input box is expanded. However it just hides underneath the grey div container. See attached image

I have tried setting `overflow:auto, max-height` properties for the parent div but nothing seems to work. Here's my code snippet.

```
<div classname={styles.greybox}>
    <div classname={styles.input}>
        <InputAreaText />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my css for parent div.

```
.greybox {
  overflow:auto;
  height: 58%;
  max-height: 800px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: sticky;
}

    .input{
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, 50px) / 75% 25%;
  column-gap: 2%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: are using floats? or have you set a fixed height to your parent? Someone will help you if you add your markup + css

Comment: @Becky not using floats. Can you provide an insight how to do that?

Comment: You should avoid floats. Use flex or grid instead. https://jsfiddle.net/huL17fzn/2/

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example that includes your HTML/CSS using the code snippets function

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="background:grey; padding:5px">

  <textarea rows="10"></textarea>

</div>
```

hope this solves your issue

Comment: no it doesnt solve the issue. What is text area? and what is the props row?